# How to get character string out from file in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have file on unix which has line with special characters also pure character string. Special character could be any like .,$%&*()-@.  sample below
  sample input

```
\302\275B\303\236Gcl\302\275t eRkAtMbn;  
Jacob  
Chinese  
39:00  
Language  
53.00
```

output:
Jacob
Chinese
Language

I want to get only pure character string lines out of this file. I have a way to read each line and compare each character with alphabets but if file is big then it will consume lot of time.

Any better approach or suggestions?

Comment: please post what tool or script you used, and sample input and expected output.

Comment: I don't know if it'll exactly meet your needs, but have a look at the 'strings' utility.  You run it by passing the file path as a command-line argument and it prints out the character strings that it finds.

Comment: im using simple shell script. i have not worked upon the code until now. Im on sunsolaris. sample input and output is written in the question.

Comment: Is your "expectation" that someone will write the code for you, or are you interested in making an attempt yourself first?

Comment: no sir that is not my expectation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is the `grep` utility.

```
grep -i '^[a-z]\+$' file.txt
```

Specifically, we're doing a case-insensitive search (`-i`) for lines that contain only the characters `[a-z]`, and only those characters from start (`^`) to finish (`$`).

Comment: I just had a closer look at your input.. are there spaces on the end of those lines?  If so, you'll need to update the regex to include space as a valid character: e.g. `[a-z ]`